# PHP Can't retrieve $_GET variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a simple DB search page, it's a personal project that is helping me learn. I am going to build a form that searches through my MTG Card collection (painfully large). I have the DB built, and queryable. In my travels through learning land I have hit a wall. This wall is the fact that I can not get $*GET variable to reassign to a variable for further use. I have trimmed down my code to just one variable for sake of ease and get anything through even on this simple simple code. It hurts my squishy student brain =*=

```
function search_mtg($_get) {
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    }

echo "Directly -->" . $_GET["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Reassigned -->" . $name;
```

The Direct call prints the key just fine. . .the reassigned variable contains NOTHING, I just don't understand why.

In case it helps, this is the (extremely simplified) form.

```
 <form action= "testResult.php" method="get">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      input type="submit">
 </form>
```

If I can't get one single variable to pass, I can't hope to continue this project T_T

Comment: Are you actually calling `search_mtg` somewhere? That is the only way the value of `$name` will be set.

Comment: `$name` is only in function's scope, you won't access it from outside

Comment: you are advised to accept the answer that helped you most, that's how it works ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple conceptual/logical errors:

```
function search_mtg($_get) {
                    ^^^^^---- do NOT redefine the superglobal variables. 
                              even though variables are case sensitive, don't re-use
                              a superglobal name, even if _get is not the same as _GET
         ^^^^^^^^^^---you never call this function
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    ^^^^^---- never gets returned
}
echo "Reassigned -->" . $name;
                        ^^^^^---never gets defined
```

You'd want, at minimum, something more like this:

```
   function search_mtg() {
      return $_GET['name'];
   }
   $name = search_mtg();
   echo $name;
```

Comment: I see that I am biting off quite a bit more than I should with this project, thank you for pointing this issues out, I'm learning quickly thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code you never call `search_mtg`, so it never executes, and never assigns anything to `$name`. What is more, even if it *did* execute, `$name` is out of scope after it executes, so the so called reassigned variable would not be printed either.

Have you trimmed the code too much, or is it like that indeed?

Comment: Those elements weren't trimmed, I didn't even realize I needed to call it ;p (noob mistake) I also wonder, would it be more efficient to put all of this in one file and use $_PHP_SELF or is modular a better practice?

Answer (score 0):

```
function search_mtg($val) {
    //You can't define a variable here $name and use it outside the scope, you have to return, unless you use `global` which is not a good practice
    return $_GET[$val];
}

echo "Directly -->" . $_GET["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Reassigned -->" . search_mtg("name");
```

**Bad Practice, don't do the one below**

```
function search_mtg($val) {
    global $name;
    $name = $_GET[$val];
}

echo "Directly -->" . $_GET["name"] . "<br>";
search_mtg("name");
echo "Reassigned -->" . $name;
```

Comment: This absolutely worked for me and the reassignment went flawlessly, Thank you sir :)